# How to define a particular purpose of an X509 certificate in PHP

Tags: php, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

How can I set the purpose of an X.509 certificate to [X509_PURPOSE_ANY](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-checkpurpose.php) in PHP 5.x?

The following code outputs this warning:

> Warning: openssl_csr_new() [function.openssl-csr-new.php]: dn: X509_PURPOSE is not a recognized name in /home/www/index.php on line 45

**PHP Script:**

```
$Configs = array(       
        'config' => 'test.cnf',
        'digest_alg' => 'sha1',
        'x509_extensions' => 'v3_ca',
        'req_extensions' => 'v3_req',
        'private_key_bits' => 2048,
        'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
        'encrypt_key' => true,
        'encrypt_key_cipher' => OPENSSL_CIPHER_3DES);

$ExtraAttribs = array('X509_PURPOSE' => 'X509_PURPOSE_ANY');

//create cert
$dn      = array('commonName' => 'Chief');
$privkey = openssl_pkey_new($Configs);
$csr     = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey, $Configs, $ExtraAttribs);
```

The last line is line 45.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the single quotes `'` from the `$ExtraAttribs` array?

Comment: Does not work. Error message: "Use of undefined constant X509_PURPOSE - assumed 'X509_PURPOSE'"

Comment: I cannot find any indication that X509 certificates have a "purpose". I can find only "Basic Constraints", "Key Usage" and "Enhanced Key Usage", are you able to do this from OpenSSL on the command line?

Comment: @Martin: I think you are right and that's the answer. So, when I create a cert with no "Basic Constraints", it must return 'X509_PURPOSE_ANY'. Will check it asap.

Comment: ok, I don't know how to add "Basic Constraints" in PHP when creating a certificate, but without any special properties set, the certificate is (according to the PHP function "openssl_x509_parse") created with the following purposes: "sslclient, sslserver, nssslserver, smimesign, smimeencrypt, crlsign, any, ocsphelper, timestampsign". So I think you were right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot find any indication that X509 certificates have a "purpose". I can find only "Basic Constraints", "Key Usage" and "Enhanced Key Usage".

The closest thing I could find is http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html which says

> For compatibility with previous versions of SSLeay and OpenSSL a certificate with no trust settings is considered to be valid for all purposes.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose is set at signing - not in the CSR. A quick look at the php docs suggest that this is not supported by the API - but you could call [openssl x509 from the shell](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html)